# Getting/Fetching information from database via Chrome Extension

Tags: php, sql, ajax, database, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently writing a chrome extension that required data to be retrieved from a MySQL database. I haven't written any code yet, but I've created a plan of action. Specifically, the extension will send an AJAX GET request to an external web server (namely a script on a domain I own). Then the script will send a request to the database and return a JSON object. Finally, the JSON object will be returned to the chrome extension to be parsed.

I have two question regarding this potential process.

1. Is this the right way to go? (I need to ask less broad questions haha)
2. If this indeed is the right way to go, how are the JSON objects meant to be returned to the Google Chrome extension (client)?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Yes, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the response! Could you give me an example of how I would pass the JSON object back to the initial GET request? I'm fairly new to PHP and that'd help a lot. Thank you again!